# Maximum Principle for Poisson Equation

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

For a smooth $u(x)$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, satisfying:

$\Delta u = -f$ for $||x||<1$ ,    $u=g$ on $||x||=1$

I want to show that there exists a constant $C$ such that:

$$\max\{|u|:||x||\leq 1\} \leq C(\max\{|g|:||x||=1\}+\max\{|f|:||x||<1\}).$$

Comment: Do you have conditions on $f$ and $g$?

Comment: There are no conditions on f and g.  C>0 depends only on n

Comment: Can this work for an exterior domain? Like same equation, but domain is $|x|>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, implicitly, $A = \|f\|_\infty$ and $B = \|g\|_\infty$ must exist.

Thus, let us consider
$$u_+(x) = B + A (1-|x|^2)$$
It is a simple matter to check that $\Delta(u_+ - u) \leq 0$ where $|x| < 1$ and that $u_+ - u \geq 0$ on $|x|=1$. The maximum principle tells you the rest.

You can analogously construct
$$u_-(x) = -B - A (1-|x|^2)$$

Using these as super and subsolutions for your problem, you can see that 
$$|u(x)| \leq A + B$$
where $|x| \leq 1$.

Comment: Could you please explain your steps in the first few lines?

Comment: (+1) your answer is more clear and direct than mine.

Comment: @rmh52: which step is confusing? -R

Comment: The expression for u+.  Im not sure how you decided to do that

Comment: Oh. The idea is, I picked $B$ for the boundary term, and for the $A$ term I wanted a function that had 0 on the boundary, and a very negative laplacian so I could invoke the maximum principle on the difference with $u$. Since $\Delta (|x|^2) = 2n$, I basically took the standard quadratic of the right sign as a function with the right properties.

Comment: I see... I'm not familiar with the notation you've used but I assume the infinity norm is the maximum of abs value?  How do I take the laplacian of u+ to verify that the difference is non-positive?

Comment: Yeah, the infinity norm is the essential supremum of a function (in this case, for $f$, on $|x| \leq 1$, and for $g$, on $|x|=1$). The reason I picked these functions is that you can explicitly calculate the laplacian:
$\Delta u_+ = \Delta B + \Delta A(1-|x|^2) = -2An$ since $A$ and $B$ are just constants.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If $u$ is a smooth function, then also $f$ and $g$ are smooth. Defined the Newtonian Potential $v$ of $f$ by $$v(x)=\int_B \Gamma(x-y)f(y)dy$$

where $B$ is the unit open ball about the origin and $\Gamma$ is the fundamental sollution of the Laplace equation. Consider the solution of the auxiliary problem $$
 \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
 -\Delta w=0 &\mbox{ in $B$} \\
  w=v-g &\mbox{ in $\partial B$}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

By unicity we conclude that $u=v-w$. Also, from the maximum principle, we have that $$\|w\|_{L^\infty(\overline{B})}\leq \|v\|_{L^\infty(B)}+\|g\|_{L^\infty(\partial B)}$$

From here, you have two things to do:

1 - Show that there exist a constan $C_1$, such that $\|v\|_{L^\infty(B)}\leq C_1\|f\|_{L^\infty(B)}$

2 - Use the representation of $u$ in terms of $v$ and $w$ to conclude.